# How do I push commits >2GB after merging two Github repositories?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I merged two repos together in a new repository following the steps outlined [here](https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/).

It worked out fine, but the merge somehow left me with 100+ un-pushed commits totaling 2.34 GB.

When I tried to push (via Github Desktop), I kept getting an error message:

[image: a screenshot of a pop-up notification after I tried to push the commits, with an error message noting: "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"]

Some of things I tried but did not work:

1. running this script:
   `git config http.postBuffer 2000000000` - I realized this basically did nothing because my commit is over 2GB.
2. pushing only select commits using this script:
   `git push -f origin <SHA of the select commit>:main` - I thought this would have allowed me to push my commits one by one as opposed to all together, it ran fine with no error message, but nothing actually got pushed.

I removed the remote to the two merged repos from the new repo. I'm not sure if that would have messed anything up.

Comment: What is in your two repos that they combined are 2+ GB in 100 commits? What does your directory structure look like, what is the size on disk?

Comment: the repos contain the code and media content for two version of my portfolio. Most of that 2+GB comes from video and image files. 

Directory structure: 
https://github.com/itsqiangwang/old-portfolio/tree/1141f7c837c05cdbe510477bb9f03981bce2f1f0

I no longer have these files locally, so I'm not sure how large they would be on disk...